# How to bind queries in codeigniter when there is a limit syntax involved

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and I'm trying to escape queries using query binding for safety, but I'm having trouble doing so using the limit syntax.

Please take a look at the query below, before I explain any further ;

**My Query**

```
   $query = "   
             SELECT * FROM messages 
             WHERE id = ? 
             AND public = ? 
             ORDER BY `messages`.`time` DESC LIMIT ?, ?
            ";

// Step one, escaping all queries          

   $bind  = array($id, $public, $start, $max); 
   $query = $this->db->query($query, $bind);        

// Step two, using the query above, and inserting it as a string into a "custom query handeler function"

   return $this->db->escape_str($this->handel_all_queries($query));
```

**Problem One :**

So, the use of `DESC LIMIT ?, ?` gives me an error. It works perfectly when its not escaped using query binding, (for example if we expressed the limit syntax  as `DESC LIMIT $start, $max`. But obviously, its unsafe to do so, and I am looking to escape it, just like the rest of the query.

**Problem Two :**

I would then like to use the "**query as a string**" in another function, that handles all query calls. The function is called `handel_all_queries`.

And the code, I've used to try and achieve this is -> `return $this->db->escape_str($this->handel_all_queries($query));`. I thought, the $query can be used as a string to transfer to the next function, but its not.

**Note**
So to put it simply, this is what I'd like to do, but these are very unprotected.

```
$query = "   
            SELECT * FROM messages 
            WHERE id = $id 
            AND public = $public 
            ORDER BY `messages`.`time` DESC LIMIT $start, $max
            ";

return $this->db->escape_str($this->handel_all_queries($query));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: the fields always escaped when u use ci query builder for the all queries so use ci query builder

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I am modifying an application that is built this way, and I need to stick to the same method to avoid rewriting the whole application.

Comment: What is the error you get in Problem One? The basic concept worked in my test.

Comment: it shouldn't work when you put two question marks next to each other, in mysql codegintier. for example `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, ?` . The error too get is `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?' at line 1`